# How to conveniently update authorized_keys file using newer (preferred) ssh key, and remove deprecated key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-agent

The use case is that I have an 1024-bit RSA key which I have used for many years to access many remote servers.

(1024 bits is not considered strong enough.  Current best practice as of 2022 suggests RSA should have at least 2048 bits).

So, I want to stop using it (don't want to load it into my ssh-agent), and instead use my newer ED25519 key.

Because I could be doing this for 50+ remote accounts, I don't want to have to manually

- load my deprecated key into ssh-agent
- try to remember how to use ssh-copy-id to copy a specific key
- manually remove the old key from the remote server
- figure out how to remove the deprecated key from ssh-agent (you'd think `ssh-add -d` or `-D` would do this?! See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330569/ssh-add-d-refused-to-remove-identity)

Instead, I want a way to do this conveniently, kind of like a beefed-up replacement of "ssh-copy-id".

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following script to handle this, which I call `ssh-update-key`.

It loads my deprecated key into ssh-agent temporarily, then uses ssh-copy-id to copy the preferred key.  Then uses some awk/sed to remove the deprecated key from the remote server.

```bash
# Filename: ssh-update-key

# Instructions:
# Set the two variables below (deprecated_key, preferred_key).
# Invoke using: ssh-update-key account@someserver.com

### Configuration

# Create ~/.ssh/deprecated directory and move your deprecated key (private and pub) into there.  Then set this variable.
deprecated_key=id_rsa

# Set this variable to your preferred key.  Should be located in ~/.ssh
preferred_key=id_ed25519


### Script 

# create symlink, so that ssh-agent will find and load the deprecated key
# (this happens automatically for me on Ubuntu 20.04)
(cd ~/.ssh && 
ln -s deprecated/$deprecated_key . && 
ln -s deprecated/$deprecated_key.pub . 
)

# copy the preferred key to the remote server
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/$preferred_key "$@"

# now remove symlinks (only if they are symlinks - don't want an accident)
(cd ~/.ssh &&
 [ -L $deprecated_key ] && rm $deprecated_key &&
 [ -L $deprecated_key.pub ] && rm $deprecated_key.pub
)
# ssh-agent does not reliably remove keys if the files are removed.
# kill it to make sure.  For me on Ubuntu 20.04 it respawns automatically.
killall ssh-agent

# Now remove deprecated key from remote authorized_keys file
# the awk regex escapes / characters which would otherwise mess up sed.
ssh "$@" -o PasswordAuthentication=no "sed -i.bak '/$(awk '{gsub(/\//, "\\/"); print $2}' ~/.ssh/deprecated/$deprecated_key.pub)/d' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

I've created a [gist for this](https://gist.github.com/jasonhildebrand/989d4196ee782e06b686d7c6a2e23d40).  Feedback/forks/improvements welcome.